# Are there only finitely many near-perfect numbers with more than 4 distinct prime divisors?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Given a positive integer $n$, let $\sigma(n)$ denote the sum of divisors
of $n$. We say that a positive integer $n$ is a *near-perfect* number
if $\sigma(n) - 2n$ is greater than $0$ and a proper divisor of $n$.

**Question:** Is it true that there are only finitely many near-perfect
numbers with more than $4$ distinct prime divisors?

Comment: Did you mean "finite *number* of even near-perfect numbers"? Also, your special number has 4 different prime divisors (not more than 4) -- how it's relevant? Also, see http://oeis.org/A181595

Comment: i say more than 4 prime factors

Comment: @qianfeng: Given that your question has already 4 pending close votes as being unclear, I have rewritten it. -- Please check whether it still asks what you intended to ask.

Comment: I don't see any argument against the value of the q.f.'s question. Thus, I'd like to keep it open.

Comment: Having in mind there are 2 solutions in the first 200 near perfect of this kind, I doubt this is true. Is it unconditionally known there are infinitely many near perfect of this kind (dropping the restriction about 4 prime factors)?

Comment: contain  just four distinct prime divisors.

Comment: An example with $5$ distinct prime divisors is $n = 2^8 \cdot 7 \cdot 19 \cdot 37 \cdot 73 = 91963648$.

Comment: i think there is no such numbers with 4 distinct divisors.but in some case ,it's hard to get o proof for me.

Comment: Why? -- $n = 3^4 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11^2 \cdot 19^2 = 173369889$ is an example.

Comment: it's an odd example.but here we only consider the even.